# Exact specification of N1-CL1 Nikon Closeup lens

Tags: lens, nikon, filters, optics

On nikon site (and everywhere else) I've been unable to find any exact specification of tne N1-CL1 filter lens -- only thing I need is to know the exact focal distance of this lens (or dioptres, or whatever else is used to measure its f-point ;] )

http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/acil/lenses/n1_cl1_closeup/index.htm

There are only some not-really-exact numbers about 3.8x zoom on 30-110mm lens.

Does anyone have this lens and could provide, for example, some real measurement? Or did I fail googling and the exact spec is listed somewhere on the internet?

Or, the pragmatically oriented question :D -- If I put it on the 30-110mm lens, what is it going to do with its focal distances and closes focus point? If they said "3.8x better zoom", does that mean it will be like 114-418mm lens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of this adapter lens is to change the minimum focussing distance of the primary lens so as to allow you to get closer and magnify the subject. In the case of 30-110mm lens, this isn't changing the focal length to be 114-418mm, that's the role of a teleconverter, the 3.8x refers to the maximum magnification of the subject. The closest working distance, in this case, is 0.24m (240 mm) from the front of the lens and that would give you that maximum magnification.

So... with the lens at 110mm and with a subject at 240mm from the lens, focussed at infinity, you would fill the frame of the Nikon 1 sensor with a subject that is 2.6mm in size.